# how could I update existed repository factors in "nexus repository manager 3.01-01"

Tags: nexus

Previously I created a maven(hosted) nexus repository for my project. Named as "project-name-private"; and for version policy, I choose category "Release". 
Now project members has new requirement to update the repository name as "project-name-dependency", and version policy should be expected as "mixed".

But I could not update those value from web repository settings, because those options are gray and they are not editable.

I had installed nexus repository manager 3.01-01, and I also have Admin Account/Password. 
I do not want to create new repository directly because there were already artifacts had uploaded in current repository, how could I fulfill project requirement to update the existed repository? expected to get your reply. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is currently not possible in Nexus Repository 3.x through the UI/a supported manner.

Please file an issue here and let us know your interest in that functionality: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS

Comment: OK, ticket submitted to track this issue [link](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-12411)     Meanwhile if is there any other solution to fulfill this requirement？e.g. modify some configuration file(.xml or other format configuration file.) ,then restart Nexus.. is it possible?    I had installed Nexus Repository 3.x in a cent OS server, but I failed to find any possible configuration files relevant with repository Names(or security policy category.. etc)

Comment: Most of this information is kept in OrientDB and then the blobs themselves. I personally haven't tested doing it (although I think it is possible) thus why I haven't given you a workaround. Watch the JIRA issue for now, the team triages these issues and might have one for you.

Comment: Thanks, I would try to get support from the Jira ticket.